# Adding a scatter to another scatter widget in kivy

Tags: android, python, kivy

I made a kivy game, with Enemys running over the screen, which are supposed to be killed by the player.

Everything works perfectly fine, but I wanted to add an weapon to my Enemy, which also has to be a Scatter, so they can by taken from the enemy by dragging them away.

Because of this both the enemy and the weapon are scatter widgets and contain a Sprite which is a super class of Image.

After adding the Weapon to the Enemy, the game still worked, but the weapon was not displayed. Why is this so?

This is the class of the Enemy:

```
class Spearman(Enemy):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Spearman, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.lay = FloatLayout()
        self.add_widget(self.lay)
        self.bron = Spear(pos=self.pos)
        self.lay.add_widget(self.bron) # the weapon is supposed to be added here
```

And this is its weapon:

```
class Spear(Scatter):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Spear, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.skura = Sprite(source = 'img/spear.png')
```

The classes are super classes of classes which work perfectly fine, and they are added to a game which is also working, so I left this code out.

I am also leaving out the import commands, because it would be to long otherwise.
Also, this is the Enemy widget:

```
class Enemy(Scatter):

    intv = NumericProperty(0/60.)
    imgp = StringProperty('img/enemy.png')
    speed = NumericProperty(1)
    gravity = NumericProperty(0.1)
    velocity = NumericProperty()
    my_start = NumericProperty()
    life = NumericProperty(5)
    amor = NumericProperty(0)
    damage = NumericProperty(0)


    def __init__(self, start=None, **kwargs):
        super(Enemy, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.My_Clock = Clock#   declaring the clock for later usage
        self.My_Clock.schedule_interval(self.Update, self.intv)
        self.pos_hint = None, None
        self.my_start = start

        self.skura = Sprite(source=self.imgp)
        self.add_widget(self.skura)

    def Update(self, *args):# the funktion that lets the enemy move
        self.x -= self.speed
        if self.y > self.my_start:#cecks if the enemy is on ground
            self.velocity += self.gravity
            self.y -= self.velocity
        else:
            if self.velocity > self.amor: # checks if amor protects the enemy
                self.life -= self.velocity
                self.velocity = 0
        if self.life <= 0: #checks if dead
            self.die()
        if self.x < 1:# checks if the enemy widget reached the end
            self.na_pierdolic()
            #self.My_Clock.unschedule(self.Update)
            self.speed = 0#makes the enemy stop moving
            if self.parent.zicie > 0:
                self.parent.remove_widget(self)
                self.My_Clock.unschedule(self.Update)


    def pause1(self, *args):# the function that lets the enemy pause
        if parent.pu == False:# check if it is paused
            self.My_Clock.unschedule(self.Update)
        elif parent.pu == True:
            self.My_Clock.schedule_interval(self.Update, self.intv1)

    def die(self, *args):
        self.parent.e_killed += 1
        self.parent.zloto += 10
        self.parent.remove_widget(self)
        self.My_Clock.unschedule(self.Update)

    def na_pierdolic(self):
        self.parent.zicie -= self.damage
```

And Here is the level widget:

```
class level(Widget):

    zicie = NumericProperty(10)# the variable containg the life of the player
    zloto = NumericProperty(0)
    e_killed = NumericProperty(0)
    intv1 = NumericProperty(2/1.)
    pu = BooleanProperty(True)
    e_start = NumericProperty()
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(level, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.l_Clock = Clock


    def Update(self, *args):# this funktion generates enemys
        estart = random.randint(4, 5)
        self.e_start = Window.height/estart
        s_start = self.e_start + 50
        pos_start = [Window.size[0],s_start]

        self.add_widget(Spearman(start=self.e_start, pos=(Window.size[0], self.e_start))) # the widget enemy is added here
        self.add_widget(Spear(start=pos_start, pos=pos_start))

        if self.zicie < 1:
            print 'you lost'
            self.l_Clock.unschedule(self.Update)
            self.clear_widgets()
    def pause(self, *args):
        if self.pu == False:
            self.pu = True
            self.l_Clock.unschedule(self.Update)
            self.clear_widgets()
        elif self.pu == True:
            self.pu = False
            self.l_Clock.schedule_interval(self.Update, self.intv1)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to draw anything in the scatter. What are you expecting to be displayed?

Comment: I do believe we need a little more information before being able to answer your question.  Or does something like `self.add_widget(self.bron)` solve your issue? In other words, it seems like you disconnect the Spearman and the Spear, so if the Spearman is displayed correctly you need to add the Spear at the same level.

Comment: Or possibly you need to add the Spear to the self.lay _before_ adding it to the current object. In other words, maybe you need to move the `self.add_widget(self.lay)` to the end?

Comment: I found a solution, by adding both the "spearman" and the "spear" to the same "level" widget, but my solution is shit, because I cant make shure that the"Sperman" and the "spear" stay together

Comment: also, here are some more information